# Visual Studio 2019 not underlining errors on Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

Visual Studio is not underlining errors. For example on my PC if type out:
private int myInt

it will put a little red underline after because i forgot ;

on my mac it does nothing making debugging a lot harder.

I did a few google searches but the only thing i find is to go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced → Underline errors. Tools doesn't have an options tab on the Mac version, and when I found the Text Editor → C# under preferences, theres no Advanced option.

Comment: `making debugging a lot harder.` Are you saying it compiled and you were able to start debugging even though the `;` was missing?

Comment: it would compile in the script, when I got to unity it would give me a compile error. Edit* I believe. I may be using the wrong terminology. I'm fairly new to this, I save the project and it updates in unity and gives me the error. On my windows version it will prompt me to fix my errors with the red underline. Same as if you misspell a word in a word processor program.

Answer (score 0):

The setting is View -> Inline Messages.  HOWEVER: This was set correctly and it still didn't work for me.  After a combination of fixing compile errors (letting it compile once) and then restarting VS, it is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and nothing worked, excepted :

`cmd`+ `shift`+ `p`

and then

`C/C++ : Enable Error Squiggles`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31289019)